# Foursquare API : check if users have the iphone app before redirecting them

Tags: javascript, api, web-applications, foursquare

I'm developing a fun little project using Foursquare API. In this project, I have a PHP/HTML page that redirects users to the foursquare app. There is no apparent issue with Android as the method we ought to use "degrade nicely".

In my HTML page, I use javascript to detect which phone the user is using. If it detects iOS, the page redirect to the Foursquare App using a URL like this "foursquare://users/USER_ID" found here : https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client

On this page, it says that I should "attempt to link to these URLs only if the user has the foursquare application installed". I followed the link Foursquare gives but it seems to give specs for iOS app and not web pages.

Evidently, Safari doesn't like at all when I try to open the "foursquare://" link without the app installed.

Is there a way to detect if the Foursquare App is installed ?

PS : my "code" looks like that :

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)){
    location.href='foursquare://venues/VENUE_ID';
}else{
    location.href='http://m.foursquare.com/venue/VENUE_ID';
}
```

EDIT : This is kind of a duplicate of this question : [Ajax call to check if native iPhone application exists on the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650654/ajax-call-to-check-if-native-iphone-application-exists-on-the-device) - Thx @Jonathan Levison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for something like: [Ajax call to check if native iPhone application exists on the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650654/ajax-call-to-check-if-native-iphone-application-exists-on-the-device)

And it appears (from that question) that you cannot find out if the native app is installed via safari mobile web browser :(

Comment: It seems I'm out of luck indeed ! Thanks for the link I didn't find ;)